# Redux-Toolkit createAsyncThunk with Typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

## Environment

1. Redux-Toolkit
2. React
3. Typescript
4. Grpahql

## Background

I'm using `redux` and `redux-toolkit` for local state management.
I read the `redux-toolkit` docs. I found that we can dispatch thunk action with `createAsyncThunk()` function in `redux-toolkit`. This function automatically dispatch `pending`, `fulfilled`, `rejected`action.

When my async work would fail, thunk dispatch `rejected` action with `action.error` as a `SerializedError` type. And we can customize the result of error with `rejectWithValue()` function. Like this.

```
const fetchAdminPassword = createAsyncThunk('adminPassword/fetch', async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
  try {
    const result = await client.query<{adminPassword: string}>({ query: FETCH_ADMIN_PASSWORD });
    const { data: { adminPassword } } = result;
    return adminPassword;
  } catch (err) {
    rejectWithValue("Error!!");
  }
});



builder.addCase(fetchAdminPassword.rejected, (state, action) => {
  state.fetchError = action.payload;
  state.fetchPending = false;
})
```

## Problem

The type of action.payload is `unknown`.

How to chanage this to `string`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things:
At this point, you still cannot know if this rejection was caused by an unknown "throw" or a `return rejectWithValue`, so even if you were to correctly type your asyncThunk, `action.payload` would end up as `string | undefined` and you would need to use check for `payload` to not be `undefined` before continuing.

That aside, you'll need to provide a generic here [as described here in the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk):

```
const fetchAdminPassword = createAsyncThunk<
  {adminPassword: string},
  void,
  {
    rejectValue: string
  }
>('adminPassword/fetch', async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
  try {
    const result = await client.query<{adminPassword: string}>({ query: FETCH_ADMIN_PASSWORD });
    const { data: { adminPassword } } = result;
    return adminPassword;
  } catch (err) {
    rejectWithValue("Error!!");
  }
});
```